# How can I access by URL to a dockerized application running in a pipeline on gitlab-ci shared runner

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using gitlab-ci with shared runners in order to setup CI in my project. It's a nodeJS API, with a shell script to for testing it and a Dockerfile to installed it.

I've already tries to access to the running docker with the service name "`docker`" through the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file but it does not work.

I want to setup 2 jobs in my CI on gitlab-ci: 
1. Build the image and push it to gitlab registry.
2. Launch the test.sh script with the url of the web API

I actually setup this for the moment in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` :

```
default:
  image: docker:stable

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY

stages:
  - build
  - test

job:build:
  stage: build
  script: docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/geocube_at_school/content-server . && docker push registry.gitlab.com/geocube_at_school/content-server

job:test:
  stage: test
  script: docker run -p 8081:8081 -d registry.gitlab.com/geocube_at_school/content-server && ./test.sh http://docker:8081
```

Here is also my `Dockerfile` just in case :

```
FROM node:latest
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install apt-utils openssl -y
COPY . /myapp/
EXPOSE 8081
WORKDIR /myapp
RUN npm install
CMD npm start
```

The script only use curl to test API endpoint on an already running application (that's why I want to provide application address through script arguments).

Comment: I don't think this is the way to test an application. In my project I use a test server where I run and test my application. One of the jobs in gitlab-ci should connect with ssh to the server and runs the docker run command there. Then you can access the application on the test server. The way you do it might work as well but you need to open port 8081 on the gitlab server and you should use a shell runner for the test job. With docker in docker it will not work

Comment: Ok i'm gonna look further, this seems a better way, thanks !